# URL rewrite using .htaccess. Which rule should I put first?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite:

`www.domain.com/entry/1` or `www.domain.com/entry/1/title` to `www.domain.com/entry.php?id=1`

`www.domain.com/entry/1/title/page/2` to `www.domain.com/entry.php?id=1&page=2`

`www.domain.com/entry/1/title/comment` to `www.domain.com/entry.php?id=1&a=comment`

I have the following in the .htaccess files

```
RewriteRule ^entry/(([0-9]+))(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ ./entry.php?id=$1  
RewriteRule ^entry/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ ./entry.php?id=$1&page=$3 
RewriteRule ^entry/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ./entry.php?id=$1&a=$3
```

It's working. I also tried reverse the orders to :

```
RewriteRule ^entry/(([0-9]+))(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ ./entry.php?id=$1  
RewriteRule ^entry/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ./entry.php?id=$1&a=$3  
RewriteRule ^entry/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ ./entry.php?id=$1&page=$3
```

It's also working. How do the lines on the .htaccess file are executed? Which of the versions above is the more correct one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter. But be sure to put an `[L]` at the end of each RewriteRule line so that Apache stops after successfully applying a rule and doesn't loop endlessly.

[This is also a very useful tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) for testing RewriteRules and whether they work correctly.